# How to get the text of a window with a timeout?

Tags: c#, c++, porting

I'm currently in the process of porting a `C++` app to `C#` and having trouble converting this particular function.
This function gets the text / title of the given window handle.

I figured out the important parts are the 2 calls to `SendMessageTimeoutW` which get the text of the window I'm assuming, but I can't figure out the rest.

I also can't find any P/Invoke signature for the UTF-16 function `SendMessageTimeoutW`, so will a call to `SendMessageTimeout` be equivalent, as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3659128)?

```
public static unsafe string GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd)
{

    // THIS PART MAY NOT BE NEEDED
    string str2 = null;
    WinHookEx* exPtr3;
    WinHookEx* exPtr = @new(4);
    try
    {
        exPtr3 = (exPtr == null) ? null : WinHookEx.{ctor}(exPtr);
    }
    fault
    {
        delete((void*) exPtr);
    }
    WinHookEx* exPtr2 = exPtr3;
    *((int*) exPtr2) = hWnd.ToPointer();
    HWND__* hwnd__Ptr = (HWND__*) hWnd.ToPointer();
    uint modopt(IsLong) num = 0;
    delete((void*) exPtr2);


    // 1st call to SendMessageTimeoutW
    if (SendMessageTimeoutW(hwnd__Ptr, 14, 0, 0, 2, 0x3e8, &num) == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // whats happening here?
    num++;
    uint modopt(IsLong) num2 = num;
    char* chPtr = @new((num2 > 0x7fffffff) ? uint.MaxValue : ((uint) (num2 * 2)));
    chPtr[0] = '\0';

    // 2nd call to SendMessageTimeoutW
    if (SendMessageTimeoutW(hwnd__Ptr, 13, num, (int modopt(IsLong)) chPtr, 2, 0x3e8, &num) == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    str2 = new string(chPtr);
    delete((void*) chPtr);
    return str2;
}
```

I have tentatively ported this function to `C#` but it always returns a **blank string**. 
I even tried initing the string builder with `new StringBuilder(256)` but it still doesn't work.

What have I done wrong?

```
public static unsafe string GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd){

    // send WM_GETTEXTLENGTH 
    if (SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, 14, 0, 0, 2, 0x3e8, IntPtr.Zero) == 0){
        return null;
    }

    // send WM_GETTEXT
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, 13, 0, sb, 2, 0x3e8, IntPtr.Zero) == 0){
        return null;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [`WM_GETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627.aspx), `wParam` (the third parameter to [`SendMessageTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx)) is

> The maximum number of characters to be copied, including the terminating null character.

You're passing zero.

Also, you're calling [`WM_GETTEXTLENGTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632628.aspx) but not using the return value:

> The return value is the length of the text in characters, not including the terminating null character.

Use that to specify the initial size of the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx). I just confirmed this to work:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var p = Process.GetProcessById(3484);
        var h = p.MainWindowHandle;

        string s = GetWindowTextTimeout(h, 100 /*msec*/);

    }


    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public unsafe static extern int SendMessageTimeout(
      IntPtr hWnd,
      uint uMsg,
      uint wParam,
      StringBuilder lParam,
      uint fuFlags,
      uint uTimeout,
      void* lpdwResult);

    const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
    const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;

    public static unsafe string GetWindowTextTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, uint timeout)
    {
        int length;
        if (SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, null, 2, timeout, &length) == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);  // leave room for null-terminator
        if (SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, (uint)sb.Capacity, sb, 2, timeout, null) == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of sending WM_GETTEXTLENGTH then, might as well use the returned value to initialize the string.

Comment: How do I use the return value of WM_GETTEXTLENGTH?

Comment: Umm the message return value is not the value returned by `SendMessageTimeout`, but the pointer passed as the last argument.

Comment: length is always coming as 1, meaning the return value is a success boolean, I have to somehow pass the pointer to an Int as the last param.

Comment: @riv Right, sorry. Been a while since I dealt with Win32 messages directly. Let's see if the other guy copies my answer this time, again.

Comment: Not sure if returning `null` in case of an empty window name is the expected behavior, but that is up to the author.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the length of the buffer.

```
int size;
SendMessageTimeout((int)hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0, 2, 0x3e8, &size).ToInt32();

if (size > 0)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size + 1);

    SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, sb.Capacity, sb, 2, 0x3e8, IntPtr.Zero)
}
```

Comment: Same as above, the value returned by `SendMessageTimeout` is not the actual value returned by the message handler.

Comment: you're write. I was thinking too much of `SendMessage`. thanks.